# How do I get DOM elements of which tagnames start with a prefix

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

Using javascript, how do I get all DOM elements that start with a certain prefix like `<prefix:suffix>`

Code example:

```
<div>
    <foo:bar1>hello</foo:bar1>
</div>
<foo:bar2>world</foo:bar2>
```

But, without looping through ALL elements (for performance reasons)?

Thanks, Ran

Answer (score 4):

With [getElementsByTagNameNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagNameNS):

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.com/namespace/for/foo", "*");
```

(Assuming you are using XHTML with elements imported from another namespace and are actually serving it with the correct content-type).

Comment: Thanks David, but unfortunately the script is supposed to be called inside other's websites making it impossible to enforce the correct doctype and content-type implementation. :-/

Comment: Throwing namespaces into arbitrary tag soup pages is a big no-no. Just don't go there. If you are providing HTML snippets, then provide HTML and not homebrew XML.